# What is the meaning of a circumflex in Java?

Tags: java

What is the meaning of a circumflex in Java?
For example:

```
textArea.setFont(font = font.deriveFont(font.getStyle() ^ Font.BOLD));
```

Are there other use cases for a circumflex in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the bitwise exclusive OR, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Ah, pretty simple! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's an exclusive OR, also called XOR